# Angular2 - Changing the global style of index.html, or applying styleurl to a route

Tags: angular

I'm using styles from bootswatch, (CSS file to replace bootstrap's CSS file) and I want to use a different one for a each route on my app (the control panel for example)
means I need a different CSS file to be applied globally when a specific route is activated
I tried removing the CSS link from `index.html` and putting it in `StyleUrls` of the primary component like  this (dummy example of one of my website's branches):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    styleUrls: ['../../../assets/css/bootstrap-simplex.css'],
    template: '<navbar></navbar><router-outlet></router-outlet>' ,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AdministrationComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router){}

}
```

Now this does change the style of this component's elements, but not to the childs or components inside its `router-outlet`

So is there a way to make styleUrls inherited to child components? or can I change the CSS link of `index.html` programatically?

thank you.

Comment: You can change the CSS link programmatically but that's not Angular2 specific (plain JS).

Comment: well I don't want that because the change functionality will be inside angular, I don't want it it be a workaround
but you mean making it a normal variable then changing it from the router right?

Comment: You can subscribe to route changes and then call the code that changes the link.

Comment: well I guess this is gonna be the only solution, didn't want to use JS to do it but it will work, thank you :)

Comment: working like charm, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was as suggested by @Günter Zöchbauer (thank you) 
is to make a js function in index.html then calling it from the component like this:

index.html

```
<link id="globalTheme" href="libs/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    var file;
    function changeTheme(section) {
        switch (section) {
            case 'primary':
                file = '-flatly';
                break;
            case 'administration':
                file = '-lumen';
                break;
        }
        document.getElementById("globalTheme").setAttribute("href",'libs/bootstrap' + file + '.min.css');
    }
</script>
```

then in the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router'

declare var changeTheme: any

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '../templates/administration.template.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AdministrationComponent{
    constructor(public router: Router){
        changeTheme('administration')
    }

}
```

hope this will be useful to someone.