# Angular2 best way to handle public and admin application, one app or multiple apps

Tags: angular

Am working on an angular application which has a front-end accessible by public and back-end which is secured. The application works as expected I however have an issue regarding how to use separate assets for public components and admin components.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
    ,AdminModule
    ,CMSModule
    ,routing
  ]
  ,declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ]
  ,bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  ,providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AdminModule** - 
admin.component.ts loads styles using `styleUrls` and `encapsulation` NONE

**CMSModule**
cms.component.ts also loads it's own styles using exact same process as above.

What I noticed is that both AdminModule and CMSModules component css is loaded, this makes sense because am telling angular to load modules which both have components loading styles with `encapsulation` NONE

Now the question I have, what is the best way to actually develop a CMS and Admin application in angular, should they be treated as two separate applications with configuration on web server routing to deployed application based on url e.g.

http://.../admin loads admin app with it own index.html and configurations and routes e.t.c

http://.../ loads cms app with it own index.html and configurations and routes e.t.c
Or is this use case easily solved using one app and some angular/js magic, has anyone done this before and how did you solve such a use case without incurring unnecessary maintenance problems.

Comment: I found post here which I must say might just be a really good solution to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278689/angular2-changing-the-global-style-of-index-html-or-applying-styleurl-to-a-ro perhaps their is another possible solution using systemjs/webpack and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating and angular service which use jQuery to manipulate the head tag, a module component would than be responsible for executing this service method addStyles so styles can directly be injected into head per module. Probably better ways of doing this, am however happy with implementation below for now.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Injectable()
export class DOMService{
  addStyles(styles:Array<string>):void{
    //remove all links from head that had been added by previous modules
    let head = jQuery("head");
    let styleElements = head.find( "[data-module-added]" );
    console.debug("current elements", styleElements)
    //add new styles passed to DOMService
    for( var i=0; i<styles.length; i++){
      let styleSheet =  styles[ i ];
      console.debug( "adding style %s", styleSheet );
      //FIXME: Maybe readfile contents and dump into head, might provide better functionality
      head.append("<link data-module-added rel='stylesheet' href='" + styleSheet + "'/>");
    }
  }
}
```